# RuntimeException The Zip PHP extension is not installed

Tags: php, linux, laravel, linux-mint, oh-my-zsh

I'm a newbie in Linux I just installed composer and laravel...

but when i run the `laravel new project` i get the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]
The Zip PHP extension is not installed. Please install it and try again.
```

I don't know how to install that extension...

please help

Comment: See this: http://serverfault.com/questions/436634/installing-php-extensions-on-linux

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try type into the command line:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`

Verify from any route with:

`dd(get_loaded_extensions());`

This worked for me, good luck.

Comment: Worked for me as well.  I am using php 7.0

Comment: what is dd(get_loaded_extensions()); and where do I verify?

Comment: @NathanSiafa   dd(get_loaded_extensions()); dumps an array of php extensions installed. If you don't see the zip extension you will need to install it as explained above. Not exactly sure what you mean "where can I verify"

Comment: ```sudo apt install php-zip``` was the solution for me. The 7.0 package was not found.

Answer (score 13):

for php 7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

for php 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```

and so on!

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue and tried to install the extension with the command `sudo apt install php7.0-zip` but still got the same error. I finally solved it with `sudo apt install php-zip`

Answer (score 1):

I was using `php7.0-zts`.
The solution was to uninstall all the `ZTS` packages and revert to the regular `php7.0` packages.

Answer (score 1):

use this `sudo apt-get install php-zip`
The php version will be sorted out by the system.

Answer (score 0):

This is outdate using brew doctor and brew cleanup. Brew doctor will give you some fixes that will help you install laravel.

`composer global require laravel/installer\n && brew install php`

Answer (score 0):

installing on CentOS

try `yum search zip |grep -i php` and install with package name came back

like - `sudo yum install ea-php73-php-zip.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

You can use php-zip or php-zip7.x package from apt. Such as:

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

Many packages in apt have a default version such as php-zip then explicit version(s). In order to search apt for packages you can always use

```
apt-cache search keyword
```

Or in this example specifically either

```
apt-cache search zip
apt-cache search php-zip
```

Which will allow you to find the php-zip and php-zip7.4 (at the time of writing this comment) package to install.

Very useful command to when you're trying to satisfy some dependency and cannot find the package name.