# The Zip PHP extension is not installed. Please install it and try again. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run:

`laravel new test`

However, I am getting this error:

[image]

I am on PHP 7.4.7 and Laravel 2.3.0 and ubunti 16.04

I ran this during the installation of PHP:

`sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-{bcmath,bz2,intl,gd,mbstring,mysql,zip}`
if this helps on what I have tried.

I am a beginner with Laravel and PHP, so please be gentle and clear with your explanations, thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: You find it's present but commented out. Have a look in the `php.ini` file and see if there's a line for the zip extension. If there is, and there's a semi-colon at the front of it, remove it, save, and reload.

Comment: Post `php -m` output.

Comment: @Mitya where is the php.ini?

Comment: @zlodes

[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter

[Zend Modules]

Comment: It seems that the zip extension is not installed in the `php` version you're using. Can you do `php -v` to verify the version that is being used? Also check `which php` and `update-alternatives --list php` and compare the outputs

Comment: post the output of `php -i | pastebinit`

Comment: @BennaWanda In whichever directory you installed your server.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Use this command:

```
php -v
```

To check php version(for me it was 7.4.9) .Then:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip
```

It will solve your problem.

Please see this answer for more.
[RuntimeException The Zip PHP extension is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511044/runtimeexception-the-zip-php-extension-is-not-installed/41202435)

Answer (score 0):

- open xampp - config Apache
  go here

[image]

- remove ; from extention=zip

[image]

- and run this commands

```
composer global remove laravel/installer
composer global require laravel/installer
laravel new my_first1
```

Comment: How do you know they are using xampp?